# CakePHP Tree Behavior issue - first entry

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, cakephp-2.2

I'm having an issue with initiating the Tree behavior issue in CakePHP. I have set up the table with `lft`, `rght` and `parent_id` columns.

I'm adding a first entry which other can refer to with the `parent_id` column. However, the referring does not work as I want.

The first entry is added to the database as expected. If I don't specify `parent_id` that column will get `NULL` as database value. The `lft` and `rght` columns is also getting `NULL` as value. I'm not sure if that's what it's supposed to do.

When I'm trying to add a new entry after the initial one, the save will fail.

I've tried to set the `lft` and `rght` columns to `1, 1` and `1, 2` on the first entry, but without any luck.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: SOLVED! It turned out that when calling the $model->save() method, sending and ID with the data (on add) kind of screws the Behavior up. So, I skipped sending an ID with it and now it works. (The reason to why I sent an ID was because I was importing data from an old table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not want to set lft and rght.  Those are handled by the framework. Do you have them defaulting to `null` as the docs specify?

I have always set the `parent_id` when using Tree Behavior and then CakePHP automagically handles the tree structure based on the parent id. if you need to move the item within the branch, then you can use the other functions of the behavior to do that.

Try setting just the `parent_id` and then save.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I just solved it. It turned out that when calling the $model->save() method, sending and ID with the data (on add) kind of screws the Behavior up. So, I skipped sending an ID with it and now it works. (The reason to why I sent an ID was because I was importing data from an old table).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on NULL and parent_id though.

Comment: That happens because the behavior only sets the tree values on record create and then using the api functions afterward.  If you were passing an ID, then Cake probably thought that you were updating at which point it would not want to alter the tree unless you specifically told it to.  Glad you got it working though!

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting but this is an undocumented part of Cake php. The docuamntation says: top element of the tree needed to set parent_id to "null".
But when you save the elemet on edit, the reorder not works because there is an interesting condition when reorder looking for the children:

```
    if ($id === null && $Model->id) {
        $id = $Model->id;
    } elseif (!$id) {
        $id = null;
    }
```

Around the TreeBehavior line 300.

So if you call reorder with id=>null and you have an $Model->id the actual tree item will be reordered only. It's wrong, i would like to reorder whole of my tree because i have changed my order field on a top category item! I think it's a kind of bug.

You have to set the id=>'' as empty, then the whole tree will be reordered. That's you want. When you editing your top tree item and would like to reorder you have to call the reorder with id=>''

```
        if(!empty($this->data['WebshopCategory']['parent_id'])){
            $this->reorder ( array('id' => $this->data['WebshopCategory']['parent_id'], 'field' => 'ordered', 'order' => 'ASC', 'verify' => true) );
        }else{
            $this->reorder ( array('id'=>'', 'field' => 'ordered', 'order' => 'ASC', 'verify' => true) );
        }
```

It will reorder whole of your tree. 
Note: with a lot of tree items the save will slow, so you have to check your order field was changed or not.